# Winforms interface freezes when updating data in the table

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, devexpress

I am using DevExpress GridControl to display data. I load data in async task and after loading updating GridControl's DataSource and Columns. Everything is great while data loading, but when I call GridControl.Invoke to update GridControl's DataSource and Columns interface freezes for some time. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Some built-in UI controls have `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` methods, that are helpful when doing a large number of updates in a loop. Maybe the `GridControl` has something similar. Otherwise, the only available option may be to load the `GridControl` with fewer data. Multithreading is not an option when it comes to updating UI components.

Comment: Show us some code, please.

Comment: execute your Invoke method inside this: new Thread(new ThreadStart() { GridControl.Invoke(); });